# onContextItemSelected - item id NullPointerException

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have ListView with custom adapter. And until now I have context menu on long press. And re-do this for click by this

```
 getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            //To register the button with context menu.
                            registerForContextMenu(getListView());
                            openContextMenu(getListView());

        }
    });
```

insted of only this

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

Before this change it works ok, but now I have NullPointerException at `info.id` and I dont know how ti fix it. Thanks for response.

```
 @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    Intent i;
    Log.d("item id", String.valueOf(item.getItemId()));
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.spotreba:    
         i = new Intent(this, SpotrebaActivity.class);
         i.putExtra("idAuta", info.id);
         startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_ADD_AUTO);
         return true;
         .
         .
         .
```

Answer (score 0):

You should register the context menu in the activity with the `ListView` and not in the inner class that u've made(onItemClickListener)..

Write it as..

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
               openContextMenu(getListView());
        }
    });
```